# Determine why or how RHEL 5.6 /root/bin folder being emptied?

Tags: linux, directory, root, redhat

I have a number of RHEL 5.6 servers all built from a single template in vmware.  These servers have a number of scripts that reside in /root/bin but on some of the servers, I'm finding that the folder contents are being purged.  It's not happening on all servers.  I'm hoping that if something is going through to delete the contents, there would be a log file entry somewhere that would note it.  Are there any software packages for Linux that might be responsible for the contents being dumped?  They are not managed by puppet.

Comment: I think you have already checked bash history, didn't you?

Comment: Yes.  rm lines for the folder don't appear in bash history so I don't believe it's human action deleting files.  And it's not s symbolic placed on top of the folder.  The server I'm sifting through now is Apache/Tomcat/PHP/SVN/NFS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the cron logs (/var/log/cron)?